# Access log4j properties in extended logger class

Tags: java, properties, log4j

I have extended Logger class of Log4j. All I want is to access of properties in log4j.properties file.
String dateFormat;
Below is my code.

```
public class TestLogger extends Logger {
    final Logger target;
    String dateFormat; //Need datePatttern from properties file
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMM-HH:mm:ss");

    public TestLogger  (Logger target) {   

        super("");      
        this.target = target;
        /**
         * Some thing that will give me **DateAppender** property 
         * to store in variable 'dateFormat'
         */
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void error(Object message, String errCode, Throwable t) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogger.class);     
        Appender appender = logger.getAppender("filer");        
        Date date = new Date();
        String msg = String.format("%1$-11s %2$-4s %3$-17s %4$s","ERROR",errCode,format.format(date),message+": "+t.getMessage());
        target.error(msg,t);
    }
```

Log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,filer,error
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.datePattern='.'MM/dd/yyyy
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyddMM-HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.appender.filer=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.filer.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.filer.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.filer.File=./trace.log
log4j.appender.filer.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.filer.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.filer.append=true
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if you would like to use your new logger class, you have to specify the full name of it in the *Log4j.properties* file, so you have to add line like the following one.

```
log4j.logger.com.TestLogger=WARN
```

Please take care of the package name also.

Every entry/line in the properties file is a set for that specific object, so automatically you will find the values in the fields of the objects hierarchy (loggert, appender and layout).